# How to display this spinner

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML code :

```
<div>   
    <input type="checkbox" class="coche" id="{{ $role_fonction->id_fonction }}" <?php if ($role_fonction->checked == 'Y') {echo 'checked';} ?>>
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" id="waiting_{{ $role_fonction->id_fonction }}" style="display: none;position:absolute;"></i>
</div>
```

When I click on the checkbox, I would like to show the spinner. How to do that in this JavaScript?

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'POST', 
        url : $('#url_for_ajax').val() + '/update_role_fonction_ajax',
        dataType : 'json', 
        data:{_token:_token, id_fonction:id_fonction,type:type,id_role:$('#id_role').val()},
            beforeSend : function() {$('#id_XXXXX').show();}, // <== to display the spinner
        success: function( data ) {     
            $('#id_XXXXX').hide();
        }              
});
```

In the HTML code, I created an articial id for the spinner: `id="waiting_{{ $role_fonction->id_fonction }}"`. So this Id is unique.

But after this, how do I get this id in my code (see the #id_XXXXX in the js code)?

Comment: What does the processed spinner HTML look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are attaching an event listener to the checkbox you can select the next element using the jQuery method `.next()`

```
$(function() {

  $('.js-checkbox').on('change', function() {
      var $nextEl = $(this).next();

      // start the spinner
      $nextEl.show();
      // do the ajax etc.

  });

});
```

Comment: perfect, it works fine. Thanks ionutvmi. And best wishes for 16.